# how can I make this code simpler

Tags: matlab

I want to make a simpler code for the following problem: I have 2 matrices called `A` and `B`:

```
A=
   [ 1     7    12    24    36    48    51    63    68    73    77    82;
     2     7    12    24    36    48    60    66    70    74    79    83]
B=
   [ 0     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1;
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     0     0     1     0]
```

and apply the following to get matrix `Res`:

```
Res = zeros(2,12);
     for x = 1:2;
        for t = 1:12;
            if B(x,t)~=0
               Res(x,t) = A(x,t) - B(x,t);
            else
               Res(x,t) = B(x,t);
            end
        end
    end


Res=
   [ 0     5    11    23    35    47    50    62    67    72    0    81;
     1     6    11    23    35    47    59    64    0     0    78    0]
```

How can I simplify my code to get `Res`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I like one-liners, so here's another solution to compete with Mark's: :)

```
Res = (A - B) .* (B ~= 0)
```

Comment: We are not worthy, we are not worthy, ...

Answer (score 2):

Hmmph, so far I've completely failed to do this in one line.  In two lines:

```
Res = A - B;
Res(B==0) = 0;
```